# Data Science: How to process and clean data when csv file has thousands of columns

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I am new in data Science and doing self learning. I have gone through all Data Science concepts and trying apply. For Data Set i visited Kaggle and picked up a Data File. However there are more than four thousands columns in csv file. So here i got stuck how to process such data because in learning all data used having less features. Please help me to provide some related document or guide here how to clean and process such data having thousand of features.

Answer (score 0):

## [Dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction)

> *In statistics, machine learning, and information theory, dimensionality reduction or dimension reduction is the process of reducing the number of random variables under consideration by obtaining a set of principal variables. It can be divided into feature selection and feature extraction.*

A lot of feature columns is not perfect for training. First of all it's computing costly and also decrese accuracy of the model.

You should try to look at [this link](https://pythonmachinelearning.pro/dimensionality-reduction/) which provides useful examples. Such as :

1. Principal Components Analysis (PCA)
2. Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA)
3. t-Distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding (t-SNE)

Also try searching for missing and duplicated values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first reduce your number of columns,  feature engineering like using Principal Component Analysis (PCA)  will help. You might reduce it to like 50 columns, this is better to work with